# CREATE TABLE syntax error using C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, ado.net

The SQL for creating Access table shows error:

```
string sql = "CREATE TABLE [" + textBox1.Text + "]([S.NO] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [Entry Date] DATETIME)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What is the error? BTW try removing the dot in the column name.

Comment: Visual Studio shows syntax error in CREATE STATEMENT. That's it. No brief explanation.

Comment: No. Didn't work. Same error.

Comment: As it turns out this question has nothing to do with `C#`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access considers `INTEGER` and `AUTOINCREMENT` to be two different data types.  Don't declare your field as both.

Also Access complained when I requested *S.NO* as a field name.  In order to get the statement to work I substituted an underscore for the dot:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [tblHarshan01]([S_NO] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, [Entry Date] DATETIME)
```